# Regex to match quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace beginning and ending quotation marks with the correct local (swiss) type of quotation marks with regex/javascript.

```
this "example": this «example»
this “example”: this «example»
this ‘example’: this ‹example›
```

Any help appreciated

What I have so far is a four step replacement:

```
replace(/["“”„](\w)/g, '«$1')
replace(/(\w)["“”„]/g, '$1»')
replace(/[‘’](\w)/g, '‹$1')
replace(/(\w)[‘’]/g, '$1›')
```

The issue with this regex: a single apostroph is getting replaced as well: that’s: that›s
I would prefer to replace the opening and closing quotes in one step.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `"that’s an example".replace(/(\w)[‘’]\W/g, '$1›')` returns `that’s an example`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Can there be quotes inside the parts between quotes like `this “exam ‘p‘le”` ?

Comment: @Barmar you're right my example works as expected. I've tested it with another one that includes umlaut: sc’ööf. \W includes umlaut characters as well. I'll need a regex that only matches spaces and punctuation at the end.

Comment: You might want to use negative lookarounds.

Comment: Note that apostrophe can appear at the end of a word when it's not quoting the word. This is used for possessives when the word is plural and ends with "s"

Comment: E.g. "my friends' houses"

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes. "this is a ’real’ example” should become «this is a ‹real› example».

Comment: @Barmar true, it's probably not a good idea to check for a character after the quote.  I think a one liner that checks both would be better. if theres a quote check if there's also an ending quote. if so replace the two by according chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex will not be fool-proof. You are probably going to have to tokenize the string and parse it.

**Note:** When nesting quotes, multiple occurrences of the same quote character will not be converted.

```js
const fixQuotes = (str) =>
  str
    .replace(/["](.+)["]/g, '«$1»')
    .replace(/[“](.+)[”]/g, '«$1»')
    .replace(/['](.+)[']/g, '‹$1›')
    .replace(/[‘](.+)[’]/g, '‹$1›');

console.log('CORRECT');
console.log(fixQuotes(`Text: "example", “example”, ‘example’`));
console.log(fixQuotes(`Text: “nested ‘example’”`));
console.log(fixQuotes(`Text: "nested 'example'"`));

console.log('INCORRECT');
console.log(fixQuotes(`Text: "nested "example""`));
console.log(fixQuotes(`Text: “nested “example””`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You would essentially have to convert twice:

```js
console.log(fixQuotes(fixQuotes(`Text: "nested "example""`)));
console.log(fixQuotes(fixQuotes(`Text: “nested “example””`)));
```

Comment: that's great, thx a lot!!
is there a reason why not combining it to this
    `.replace(/["“](.+)["”]/g, '«$1»').replace(/['‘](.+)['’]/g, '‹$1›')`

Comment: if only aphostroph are used it doesn't replace opening and ending quote:
’that’s an example’. Not a big issue anyway.